# replace "*,*" with "**" in a csv file

Tags: regex, bash, perl, csv, replace

I get .csv files with lot of different details and recently, sizes and epoch values were added to it. This is causing issues with the import tool due to unwanted (,) within values

e.g.

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6
abc,edf,"123,456,789","1,234","133,233,456",20/01/2016
ogfsf,dcfdc,0,"1,456","134,567,456",11/01/2016
jkglt,mnbc,0,0,"132,467,876",05/01/2016
```

I want to replace the unwanted (,) that come in between ("") in each row. I tried using sed, tr and other type of replacements, but that didn't help. Do I need to use scripts to do this or a single liner replacement command will do?

Regards

Comment: It's certainly doable with both `sed` and `awk`.  What did you try?  Of course, the best solution would probably be to teach your import tool to handle commas in quoted strings correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sed:

```
sed -E ':a;s/((,|^)"[^",]*),/\1/;ta' file
```

details:

```
:a # define the label "a"
s/((,|^)"[^",]*),/\1/ # replace the first comma enclosed between quotes
ta # if something is replaced, go to label "a"
```

The -E (or -r) switch sets the regex syntax to ERE (Extended Regular Expression) that allows `|` and avoids to escape all special characters like parenthesis.

`(,|^)` is here to check if the quote is really an opening quote. Since commas are replaced one by one from left to right, when it matches, you can be sure that the following quote is an opening quote (because all previous commas inside quotes are already replaced).

Note: This assumes that quoted parts of your csv file don't contain newlines. To handle quoted parts with newlines, it's a bit more complicated since you need to check if the number of quotes is even and if not, you need to append next lines to the pattern space until you obtain an even number of quotes:

```
sed -E ':a;/^([^"]|"[^"]*")*$/!{N;ba};:b;s/((,|^)"[^",]*),/\1/;tb' file
```

To deal with escaped quotes:

```
sed -E ':a;/^([^"]|"[^"]*(""[^"]*)*")*$/!{N;ba};:b;s/((,|^)"[^",]*(""[^",]*)*),/\1/;tb;' file
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer !

Answer (score 6):

Because you have quoted commas, you need a parser. `regex` can do it, but it's nasty, where something like `perl`s [`Text::CSV`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) parses just fine.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV -> new ( { binary => 1, eol => "\n" } ); 

while ( my $row = $csv -> getline ( \*DATA ) ) {
   #remove commas in fields in the row
   s|,||g for @$row; 
   #print the row. 
   $csv -> print ( \*STDOUT, $row ); 
}

__DATA__
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6
abc,edf,"123,456,789","1,234","133,233,456",20/01/2016
ogfsf,dcfdc,0,"1,456","134,567,456",11/01/2016
jkglt,mnbc,0,0,"132,467,876",05/01/2016
```

This prints:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6
abc,edf,123456789,1234,133233456,20/01/2016
ogfsf,dcfdc,0,1456,134567456,11/01/2016
jkglt,mnbc,0,0,132467876,05/01/2016
```

As desired. You can use `\*STDIN` to read... from STDIN. Or you could use [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) to do file IO.

If you want something specifically to 'one-liner' it for use in a script (which IMO is the usual reason for asking for a regex type solution):

```
perl -ne 'BEGIN{$csv = Text::CSV->new({eol=>"\n"})} $csv->print(\*STDOUT, [map {s|,||gr} do {$csv -> parse ( $_ ); $csv ->fields()}])' filename
```

Which does more or less the above, and ... well, there's a tradeoff - the `regex` bit is pretty clear, but the `map` might be a bit inscrutable :).

This is:

- iterating line by line (filename or stdin)
- calling `parse

Comment: Hooray, a proper answer!

Comment: I have a new crusade against inappropriate use of `regex`. I see a lot of "can I have a regex for..." questions which whilst _technically_ regular expressions could do, the resultant regex ends up ... well, the epitome of 'bad code' in that it's hard to read or understand. (See some of the answers below for examples of what I mean - they're _correct_ but hard to follow)

Comment: Me too. regex is a good hammer, but not every problem needs a hammer. Formats like XML, JSON, CSV require proper parsers for non-fragile solutions.

Comment: @Sobrique , Thanks for the helpful answer, but I've chosen the sed answer..

Answer (score 1):

Why not make columns 3,4,5 before export a value without the , ? According to what you tell the export file is getting changed by adding column of different types, it is essential to tell te people who make the first export that they have to export it as a xxxxxxxxxx number instead of a xxx,xxx,xxx number.

It is done in a jiffy in MS excel or Ooo, now your making a code , which will eventually give more problems while the problem is created by the first user.

Put it in a white paper how the exports should go; text files, columns etc. it makes life for a programmer much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Through perl,

```
$ perl -pe 's/,(?!(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)//g' file
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6
abc,edf,"123456789","1234","133233456",20/01/2016
ogfsf,dcfdc,0,"1456","134567456",11/01/2016
jkglt,mnbc,0,0,"132467876",05/01/2016
```

Through python.

```
>>> import re
>>> with open('/home/gemini/Desktop/sample.txt') as f:
        m = f.read()
        print re.sub('"[^"]*"', lambda x: x.group().replace(',', ''), m)


col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6
abc,edf,"123456789","1234","133233456",20/01/2016
ogfsf,dcfdc,0,"1456","134567456",11/01/2016
jkglt,mnbc,0,0,"132467876",05/01/2016
```

Answer (score 0):

Teach your importer to handle quotes:

```
B = []
for line in csv:
    A = line.split('"')#A is now a list of strings in which every other element is within quotes
    inquotes = False
    for item in A:
        if(inquotes):
            B.append(item)
        else:
            C = item.split(',')#This is the regular csv stuff, the one we parse by commas
            for element in C:
                 B.append(C)
        inquotes = not(inquotes)#change state
```

This is kind of hacky, but will preserve the commas instead of removing them

Answer (score 0):

Here's a ruby one-liner that will blindly remove any commas from quoted entries:

```
ruby -rcsv -e 'CSV.foreach(ARGV.shift) {|row| puts CSV.generate_line row.map {|elem| elem.delete(",")}}' file.csv
```

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6
abc,edf,123456789,1234,133233456,20/01/2016
ogfsf,dcfdc,0,1456,134567456,11/01/2016
jkglt,mnbc,0,0,132467876,05/01/2016
```

If you have data like

```
"hello,world",foo,"1,234"
```

you will want to keep the commas in the string fields. In that case

```
$ cat file.csv
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6
abc,edf,"123,456,789","1,234","133,233,456",20/01/2016
"a,b,c","d,e,f",0,0,0,0

$ ruby -rcsv -e '
    CSV.foreach(ARGV.shift) do |row| 
      puts CSV.generate_line (
        row.map do |elem| 
          elem.match(/^\d+(,\d\d\d)+$/) ? elem.delete(",") : elem 
        end
      ) 
    end
  ' file.csv
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6
abc,edf,123456789,1234,133233456,20/01/2016
"a,b,c","d,e,f",0,0,0,0
```

Answer (score 0):

Dedicated CSV parsers can definitely do that though using standard shell utilities here is one simple gnu-awk solution:

```
awk -v FPAT='"[^"]*"|[^,]*' -v OFS=, '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) gsub(/,/, "", $i)} 1' file
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6
abc,edf,"123456789","1234","133233456",20/01/2016
ogfsf,dcfdc,0,"1456","134567456",11/01/2016
jkglt,mnbc,0,0,"132467876",05/01/2016
```

`-v FPAT='"[^"]*"|[^,]*'` breaks each line into fields as `"..."` or non-comma fields.

Comment: the above removes all (,), not only the (,) within (").

Comment: That's not true, you can see attached output with all the commas outside quotes intact.